# How can I change the cluster color using gvmap?

Tags: graphics, graph, visualization, graph-visualization, information-visualization

I have a .dot file below. I can draw a map visualization by using this command "sfdp -Goverlap=prism INPUT.gv | gvmap -e |  neato  -n2  -Ecolor=#55555522 -Tpng > OUTPUT.png".

```
 graph {
  "0" [cluster="3", label="Drawing", pos="26.163,130.97"];                        
  "1" [cluster="3", label="Visualization", pos="270.82,243.14"];           
  "2" [cluster="2", label="Graph", pos="271.43,16.263"];        
  "3" [cluster="2", label="Arizona", pos="670.15,16.263"];        
  "4" [cluster="2", label="University", pos="415.11,16.263"];          
  "5" [cluster="1", label="Map", pos="513.44,131.26"];   
  "0" -- "1";    
  "1" -- "2";  
  "0" -- "2";   
  "3" -- "4";      
  "5" -- "1";  
  "5" -- "2";  
}
```

the algorithm behind GraphViz assigns color to my clusters. So the output is an image like bellow.

[image]

How can I assign my own colors to the clusters instead of colors used by the algorithm?

Thansk

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Based on this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/gvmap-1.html,

you can add this modifier to the command you use in the gvmap section to create the graph:
*-c k The integer k specifies color scheme used to color  the
          countries. By default k = 1.*

```
    Acceptable values are:
         0 : no polygons
         1 : pastel
         2 : blue to yellow
         3 : white to red
         4 : light grey to red
         5 : primary colors
         6 : sequential single hue red
         7 : sequential single hue lighter red
         8 : light grey
```